# How to send an HTTP Response for an incoming request using python sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server, httpresponse

I have the a python server coded to work on http://127.0.0.1:9999/. The server prints out the incoming http request. I have also coded on what headers to be sent during the response and also the content. Here is the code:

```
import socket
from time import sleep
c = None #Client socket1
addr = None #Client address1
    
server_socket1 = socket.socket() #by default it is SOCK_STREAM (TCP) and has porotocal AF_INET (IPv4) 

server_socket1.bind(('127.0.0.1',9999)) #server machine's ip and port on which it will send and recieve connections from

server_socket1.listen(2) #We will only accept two connections as of now , one for each client
print("Server started successfully!!!")
print("Waiting for connections...\n\n")

while (((c is None)and(addr is None))):
    if((c is None) and (addr is None)):
        c,addr = server_socket1.accept()
        print("User connected to client1 socket!!")
        c.send(bytes("Connected to the apps server!!!","utf-8"))
        print("Client connected ip address "+str(addr))
        

        
while True:
    msg = c.recv(4096)
    if(msg!=None):
            #print(msg)
            headers, sep, body = msg.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')
            headers = headers.decode('utf-8') 
            print(headers)

            html_body = "<html><body><h1>This is a test</h1><p>More content here</p></body></html>"
            response_headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html; encoding=utf8',
            'Content-Length': len(html_body),
            'Connection': 'close',
            }

            response_headers_raw = ''.join('%s: %s\r\n' % (k, v) for k, v in response_headers.items())
            response_proto = 'HTTP/1.1'
            response_status = '200'
            response_status_text = 'OK' # this can be random

            # sending all this stuff
            r = '%s %s %s\r\n' % (response_proto, response_status, response_status_text)
            c.sendall(r.encode())
            c.sendall(response_headers_raw.encode())
            c.sendall(b'\r\n') # to separate headers from body
            c.send(html_body.encode(encoding="utf-8"))

            sleep(5)
```

The code works without compilation errors, starts the server and captures the request i send from the browser intended. But, while sending the response, the socket connection closes with an error as **[WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**.

Request sent from the browser :

[image]

The Output in the terminal :

[image: Error while sending response to the browser]

The error displayed in browser :

[image: Browser window]

What may be causing this error? Previously python prompted me with an error that the object must be a byte type and not type 'str' while sending response_headers_raw variable. Hence I used the encode() function to convert it to a byte type object which has led me to this error.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

~regards

Comment: first of all, why are you using so many brackets everywhere? `while (((c is None)and(addr is None)))`

Comment: recommend using this library, https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#creating-a-server-instance. There is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Any suggestions how to improve upon the existing codebase? I want to develop a server without using any frameworks or libraries to implement and learn the socket programming concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    c,addr = server_socket1.accept()
    print("User connected to client1 socket!!")
    c.send(bytes("Connected to the apps server!!!","utf-8"))
```

You send *"Connected to the apps server!!!"* to the client immediately after connect. The client is expecting a HTTP response though. Since it gets your non-HTTP data the client closes the connection. Later `c.sendall` will write to a socket closed by the peer which results in *"An established connection was aborted"*.

In addition to this ...

```
msg = c.recv(4096)
if(msg!=None):
        #print(msg)
        headers, sep, body = msg.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')
```

Your expectation seems to be that `c.recv` will return `None` when the socket is closed. This is not true, it will return `''` instead. This means that even after the first error is fixed your code will again run into a similar problem if the peer has closed the connection after successfully reading the request and sending the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I removed that line and it worked like charm! :)